# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak. cancel all subscriptions an

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-component-unmount

I am passing props from a child nested inside a class component

```
class Viewer extends React.Component {
....
render(){
return(
.....
<DragAndDrop characters={characters}/>
)
}
```

to the parent functional component

```
function DragAndDrop(props) {
  console.log("char",props.characters); # I am able to console.log this
  const [characters, updateCharacters] = useState(props.characters); # but doing this throws an error 

  function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const items = Array.from(characters);
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);

    updateCharacters(items);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Final Space Characters</h1>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
          <Droppable droppableId="characters">
            {(provided) => (
              <ul
                className="characters"
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
              >
                {characters.map(({ id, name, thumb }, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Draggable key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                      {(provided) => (
                        <li
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        >
                          <div className="characters-thumb">
                            <img src={thumb} alt={`${name} Thumb`} />
                          </div>
                          <p>{name}</p>
                        </li>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  );
                })}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </ul>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DragAndDrop;
```

but when I pass `props.characters` to useState, it throw an error, How I can resolve this? thanks

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak. cancel all subscriptions an
```

Comment: What error are you getting - that might be useful

Comment: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak. cancel all subscriptions an

Comment: Post more info of DragAndDrop component. You can skip the return value of it, we just need to see the functions inside of it

Answer (score -1):

This problem take place because you initialize state before mount component.
If you want to correct your component you can use useEffect inside your component and inside that updateCharacters like below

```
useEffect(()=>{
      updateCharacters(props.characters);
}, [])
```

Dependency array is required if you don't want the component rerendering infinitely